# Process cannot be resumed after having been suspended

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, process, resume

CreateProcess suspended but it can't be resumed.

Here is my code:

```
bool success=CreateProcess(m_Process,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             FALSE,
             NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS||CREATE_SUSPENDED,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             &suInfo,
             &procInfo);

if(!success){
    MessageBoxA(0,"Could not create process...","ERROR",MB_OK);
    return 1;
    }

    //we created it

//all good so go!
ResumeThread(procInfo.hThread);
```

Why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove one of the "|". This ends up as a one since it's a logical expression in your case. The constant for this is DEBUG_PROCESS, so you're debugging the child process.

Comment: Why DEBUG_PROCESS? The question said nothing about debugging the child process, just starting it suspended.

Not marking down because the first two sentences of your answer are correct.

Comment: Read my answer again: NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS||CREATE_SUSPENDED equals "1" which in turn equals to the DEBUG_PROCESS define.

Comment: Oh, I see. You were explaining what the OP got, not what they should do. Apologies - makes sense.